# Change date format into Dutch language

Tags: php, date

I have a date format in English and i want to change it into Dutch language.

my code is:

```
$date_arr = explode('-', $eventPublishDate);
$datetime= mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_arr[1], $date_arr[2], $date_arr[0]);
$enterted_date  = date("jS F Y",$datetime);
$newDate = date("jS F Y", strtotime($eventPublishDate));
```

I tried below code but not able to find suffix [th, nd...] of date

```
if ( setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nld_nld' ) || setlocale( LC_ALL, 'nl_NL' ) ) {
    $newDate =  strftime("%d  %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_arr[1], $date_arr[2], $date_arr[0]));
}
```

I need output in : 15th januari 2014

please help me sort out the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the intl module:

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'nl_NL',
     IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
     IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
echo $fmt->format(mktime(null, null, null, 1, 15, 2014));

// output: 15 januari 2014
```

Comment: trying to convert date into my language - this solution was the only one working (if I exclude str_replace)

Answer (score 9):

Ok, if this doesn't work:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl'); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); 
echo strftime('%a %e %B %Y',time());
```

Try to pass the English output to this old but useful function by Erik Jan. It will return simple replaces...

```
/** 
     * @author http://netters.nl/nederlandse-datum-in-php 
     */ 
    function nlDate($datum){ 
      /* 
       // AM of PM doen we niet aan 
       $parameters = str_replace("A", "", $parameters); 
       $parameters = str_replace("a", "", $parameters); 

      $datum = date($parameters); 
     */ 
       // Vervang de maand, klein 
      $datum = str_replace("january",     "januari",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("february",     "februari",     $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("march",         "maart",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("april",         "april",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("may",         "mei",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("june",         "juni",         $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("july",         "juli",         $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("august",         "augustus",     $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("september",     "september",     $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("october",     "oktober",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("november",     "november",     $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("december",     "december",     $datum); 

      // Vervang de maand, hoofdletters 
     $datum = str_replace("January",     "Januari",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("February",     "Februari",     $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("March",         "Maart",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("April",         "April",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("May",         "Mei",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("June",         "Juni",         $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("July",         "Juli",         $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("August",         "Augustus",     $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("September",     "September",     $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("October",     "Oktober",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("November",     "November",     $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("December",     "December",     $datum); 

      // Vervang de maand, kort 
       $datum = str_replace("Jan",         "Jan",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Feb",         "Feb",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Mar",         "Maa",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Apr",         "Apr",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("May",         "Mei",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Jun",         "Jun",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Jul",         "Jul",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Aug",         "Aug",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Sep",         "Sep",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Oct",         "Ok",             $datum); 
     $datum = str_replace("Nov",         "Nov",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Dec",         "Dec",             $datum); 

      // Vervang de dag, klein 
     $datum = str_replace("monday",         "maandag",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("tuesday",     "dinsdag",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("wednesday",     "woensdag",     $datum); 
     $datum = str_replace("thursday",     "donderdag",     $datum); 
     $datum = str_replace("friday",         "vrijdag",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("saturday",     "zaterdag",     $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("sunday",         "zondag",         $datum); 

      // Vervang de dag, hoofdletters 
       $datum = str_replace("Monday",         "Maandag",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Tuesday",     "Dinsdag",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Wednesday",     "Woensdag",     $datum); 
     $datum = str_replace("Thursday",     "Donderdag",     $datum); 
     $datum = str_replace("Friday",         "Vrijdag",         $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Saturday",     "Zaterdag",     $datum); 
      $datum = str_replace("Sunday",         "Zondag",         $datum); 

      // Vervang de verkorting van de dag, hoofdletters 
       $datum = str_replace("Mon",            "Maa",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Tue",         "Din",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Wed",         "Woe",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Thu",         "Don",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Fri",         "Vri",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Sat",         "Zat",             $datum); 
       $datum = str_replace("Sun",         "Zon",             $datum); 

      return $datum; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new array

```
$lang = array();
$lang['en'] = ['january','februari','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december'];
$lang['nl'] = ['januari','februari','maart','april','mei','juni','juli','augustus','september','oktober','november','december'];
```

Replace it to the dutch format

```
ucfirst(str_replace($lang['en'], $lang['nl'], strtolower($datum)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try change this line:

```
$enterted_date  = date("jS F Y",strtotime($datetime));
```

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you may create an array of months and days in your language, and use foreach loop to replace values:

```
$arr = array('Maa', 'Din','Woe','Don', ...);
$date = date('D M Y');
```

and then:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $V){
   $date = str_replace($k, $v, $date);
}
echo $date;
```

This was the second solution for my case (first one was @gontrollez). Set locale for me didn't work at all, and this solution with array does not seems to me as very elegant.