# Echo date in dutch format

Tags: php

How can I `echo` the `current date + 2 month`s` in Dutch format?

I have tried the following:

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');
echo strftime('%e %B %Y'(' +2 month'));
?>
```

When I run this code I get a error on my page. How can I fix this and run echo the date in Dutch format?

Comment: https://forums.modx.com/thread/71553/how-to-change-date-notation-to-other-local-language     And      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421532/change-date-format-into-dutch-language     And     https://www.phphulp.nl/php/script/overig/datum-in-het-nederlands/239/

Comment: Nothing with `+ month`. I have the code working without `+ month`. The combination of this is not working.

Comment: Just syntax error. try `strftime('%e %B %Y', strtotime('+2 month'))`

Answer (score 3):

```
$timestamp = time();
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y', $timestamp);
```

More about strftime [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Comment: Ok, now I need to do `+ 2 month` where do I need to write this?

Comment: strftime is deprecated in php 8

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a basic dictionary for it, but here it is:

```
function dutch_strtotime($datetime) {
    $days = array(
        "maandag"   => "Monday",
        "dinsdag"   => "Tuesday",
        "woensdag"  => "Wednesday",
        "donderdag" => "Thursday",
        "vrijdag"   => "Friday",
        "zaterdag"  => "Saturday",
        "zondag"    => "Sunday"
    );

    $months = array(
        "januari"   => "January",
        "februari"  => "February",
        "maart"     => "March",
        "april"     => "April",
        "mei"       => "May",
        "juni"      => "June",
        "juli"      => "July",
        "augustus"  => "August",
        "september" => "September",
        "oktober"   => "October",
        "november"  => "November",
        "december"  => "December"
    );

    $array = explode(" ", $datetime);
    $array[0] = $days[strtolower($array[0])];
    $array[2] = $months[strtolower($array[2])];
    return strtotime(implode(" ", $array));
}
$date = "woensdag 22 oktober 2014 08:41:42";
echo date("l d-m-Y H:i:s", dutch_strtotime($date)) . "<br />";
echo date("d-m-Y", dutch_strtotime($date));
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k51z-9n6j

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime to get the timestamp for the date two months from now.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Then supply the timestamp as the second argument for strftime

```
<?php 
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');
    $timestamp = strtotime("+2 months");
    echo strftime('%e %B %Y', $timestamp);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

month is not correct check possibility with these function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

```
 <?php 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . " +2 month");
?>
```

also  your  variable  `$months` `function dutch_strtotime` and `echo strftime('%e %B %Y'(' +2 month'));` check it

Comment: I get: Line : 3,   Error type : 4 Message : syntax error, unexpected '('

Comment: try this <?php 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl.UTF-8');
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . " +2 month");
?>

Comment: I get the result: `1471665600`