# I would like to use PHP code in Wordpress that display's inside a dropdown menu

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, shortcode

I got an problem.

I would like to display the next sunday from the week in an dropdown menu.

got the PHP code right here:

```
echo date("j, M", strtotime("next sunday"));
```

I also made this A shortcode in Wordpress so I can use this code in pages.

```
function WebinarDaySunday() {
    echo date("j, M", strtotime("next sunday"));
}
add_shortcode('webinardaysunday', 'WebinarDaySunday');
```

Only problem is, The Echo is put on the left corner of the page, and not in the location I would like it to be(inside the dropdown). The shortcode is in the correct place but the echo goes into the left corner.

If anyone know's how to get the output in the correct location I would really appreciate that

I put a screenshot of the result and where I would like the outcome to be.

[The link to the screesshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aQMr.png)

Best regards,

Bas.

Comment: What other content do you have in the dropdown menu? And how is it generated?

Comment: Here is the code
<p style="text-align: center;"><select name="dropdown-content" class=" dropdowncontent-dropdown"> <option value="">Selecteer de datum</option>
 <option value="”option1″">Zondag,  </option>
 <option value="”option2″">Maandag,&nbsp; </option>
 </select>
 </p>

Comment: It is created by a Wordpress plugin called Dropdown Content

Comment: Where are the values `Zondag`, `Maandag` etc present? Are you entering them manually in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes they are there manually, placed them info the page editor from Wordpress itself

Comment: Then nextto the Zondag, Maandag I placed the selfmade short code that calls in the PHP script for the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the date value in your shortcode function instead of using echo. See if that works

Comment: Thanks for your commend, could you give an example of code on how to do this?

Comment: function WebinarDaySunday() {
    $date = date("j, M", strtotime("next sunday"));
    return $date;
}
add_shortcode('webinardaysunday', 'WebinarDaySunday');

Comment: Right now I have added the day to the code, so like $date = date("l, j, M", strtotime("tomorrow"));

I would like the day to be translated to Dutch, how Do i do this? Best regards, Bas.

Comment: I am not aware of any other php functions or libraries for this but someone created a simple solution you could use here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37914913/7077417